# Error happened when using gpu to run Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I was trying to build a CNN model using Keras, and I download gpu version of Tensorflow(since I have GTX 1050Ti). Everything runs correctly (importing and set up model), until I wanna fit the data to the model, and an error as follows happened. I also tested the code on an environment with only cpu, everything works fine. I am wondering if there a problem with my gpu set up? If it is, how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
2018 01:54:24.393675: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018 01:54:24.660254: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.62
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.29GiB
2018 01:54:24.662362: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018 01:54:25.310183: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018 01:54:25.310808: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:929] 0 
2018 01:54:25.311107: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:942] 0: N 
2018 01:54:25.311512: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3026 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018 01:54:28.587566: E T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:462] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2018 01:54:28.588197: E T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:462] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2018 01:54:28.601085: E T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:462] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2018 01:54:28.601751: E T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:462] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2018 01:54:28.602208: E T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:462] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2018 01:54:28.602798: E T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:462] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2018 01:54:31.121650: E T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:455] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2018 01:54:31.122851: F T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:713] Check failed: stream‑>parent()‑>GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(), &algorithms)
```

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the GPU ran out of memory as it can be seen from the log. When running on the CPU, the data will be feed to the system memory, which I think in your system would be greater than 4GB, so there is no error. To reduce the memory requirement, you could try smaller data batch when fitting the model to the dataset.